# Can only connect to various HTTP services (game patchers, Unity Store, NuGet) from one wireless network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-8.1, dns

Ever since I've connected my (Windows 8.1 running) laptop to the (rather weirdly set up) university halls wireless network (well it might be actually be the wired, but I doubt it), it won't connect to many services provided through HTTP. Not all of them, but for example, take: EVE Online patcher, League of Legends RADS client, Unity Store, NuGet Package Manager.

The files these clients can't access can be freely accessed through my browser. Last time I had this problem (because of being away for two weeks) I've had to do a complete reinstall, since I couldn't fix the issue.

What I've tried:

- Flush DNS
- Release and renew IP settings
- Reset network adapter DNS settings
- Try setting a public DNS provider
- Reinstall network drivers

The network, naturally, was tested with another laptop to see if there is any issue, but there was no issue with the network. On the other hand, I've tried several wireless connections to use these services, but none of them worked, so there is certainly something wrong with my laptop. Firewall and antivirus are not an issue, since the game works perfectly on the university halls network.

Not sure if it helps, but IPConfig /all's output is:

```
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : dlink.com
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : E4-D5-3D-ED-74-4B
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::c011:b1e9:8dc0:c809%38(Preferred)
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.3(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 29 August 2014 22:04:33
Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 30 August 2014 22:04:33
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 652531005
DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1A-46-29-CC-24-B6-FD-09-A7-EA
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

UPDATE: It seems these clients are returning with an error 407: Proxy authentication required. (Well at least some of them, the rest are only returning generic errors.) I've checked Internet Explorer's settings, however it doesn't seem like I have anything like that turned on.

Comment: What time of connection did you specify when you first connected?  Did you allow sharing or not? i.e. http://www.tomsguide.com/us/win8-tips-tricks,review-1778-15.html

Comment: I specified it as a home network, so yeah, sharing is on.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it turned out that there was a cached proxy set up in the registry under the key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Environment\HTTP_PROXY (So in the system Environmental variables). I'll look for additional entries like this one, since it only solved a few of those problems so far, Unity Store still refuses to work, but at least it's a progress.